# Dissatisfied with/about

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-difference

What is the difference between "**dissatisfied with**" and "**dissatisfied about**"? Which is more common?

- I am dissatisfied with/about his fooling me.

Comment: No difference.  "Dissatisfied about" is used, according to Ngram, but much more rarely than "(dis)satisfied **with**".  I, personally, wouldn't use it.

Comment: So, **about** is the least common preposition with (dis)satisfied?

Comment: @Andrew in COCA, 'dissatisfied with' has freq of 858 while 'dissatisfied about' only 1.

Comment: @Zulkanien Link please.

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't allow me to copy the link. You have to try it yourself here: https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/

Comment: The preposition "with" being, without doubt, the most frequent, the other prepositions - together with "about" - which may follow the adjective dissatisfied are "in", "at", and "by"; the latter two are used more frequently than "about" and  "at" is used nearly two times more frequently (you may check Google Ngram if you wish). The least common is "in"

Comment: @Rompey You are right. Is there a difference between them all? Some shade of meaning maybe?

Comment: With your command of English, to feel it, you can read the sentences the Ngram provides, I believe. To me, the nuances are too subtle to suggest a good answer :-)

Comment: Interestingly, the frequency [changes a bit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsatisfied+with%2Cunsatisfied+about%2Cunsatisfied+by%2Cunsatisfied+at%2Cunsatisfied+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunsatisfied%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsatisfied%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsatisfied%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsatisfied%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsatisfied%20in%3B%2Cc0) with "unsatisfied", "with" remaining the safest choice.

Comment: As the question "Which is more common" has already been answered, I think that in the sentence "I am dissatisfied with his fooling me" the prepositions alternative to "with" is sooner not "about" but "at" or "by". 
(For the possibility of using "at" and "by" after the adjective dissatisfied meaning "displeased" [ not just "not satisfied"] see here()[https://books.google.ru/books?id=l9g3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&dq=%22dissatisfied+at%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO39qg7dHWAhWBYpoKHW8MBzQQ6AEIUzAG#v=onepage&q=%22dissatisfied%20at%22&f=false])

Comment: @SovereignSun In the few examples of "dissatisfied about", I don't see that the meaning would change in any way if you swapped in *with* for *about*.  I imagine if we dug deep enough we'd find some common element between the examples, like the writers are all from a certain region or use a similar dialect where this phrasing is (or was) common.

Comment: Could somebody please provide an answer?